# debugging with radare2

Tags: x86, radare2

I am using radare2 for disassemble an x86 binary:

```
$ r2 ./mynbinary
[0x00001000]> aaa
...
[0x00001000]> pdf
            ;-- section..text:
            ;-- section.LOAD1:
            ;-- rip:
/ (fcn) entry0 53
|   entry0 ();
|           ; UNKNOWN XREF from 0x00001000 (entry0)
|           0x00001000      e800000000     call loc.suite              ; [15] m-r-x section size 53 named LOAD1
            ;-- suite:
|           ; CALL XREF from 0x00001000 (entry0)
|           0x00001005      48b968656c6c.  movabs rcx, 0x3332316f6c6c6568
...
```

As you can see it works great.

Now, i am doing the same thing, on the same binary but with -d option in order to debug the binary

```
[0x7ff5a7183210]> aaa
...
[0x7ff5a7183210]> pdf
p: Cannot find function at 0x7ff5a7183210
```

I don't know why it does not work in debuging...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that address `0x7ff5a7183210` is not part of your binary but rather part of the kernel code that will run your code. So running `aaa` will not create any functions there. What you need to create a breakpoint in your code (i.e running `db main`) and only when your breakpoint is hit you could run `pdf` and it should should show you the disassembly.